# Condition in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure that does 2 updates, but i only want to do the first update if the parameter `@active` is equals to `'Y'`.

```
alter procedure sp_updateThis
@something varchar(5),
@active char(1)
as begin
-- check to see if active and do the update
update myTable set this=@something

-- run this one regardless
update yourTable set that=@something
```

Comment: Are you trying to update every row in the table, or a specific row?

Comment: Also [please use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx) and [don't use `sp_` for stored procedure names](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: Thanks Arron for the link! i guess i'm doing it the old way :( iwas always taught to prefix everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing that last line with this:

```
if (@active = 'Y')
begin
    update yourTable set that=@something
end
```

Comment: As Aaron Bertrand just stated, this update is going to update EVERY row in that table.  If this is not the intended result, be sure to add a `WHERE` clause on your update!

Comment: yes thank you, this was just an example. i have my where statements in place :) Begin and End is what i was missing! thanks again!

Comment: @TanyaXrum - `BEGIN ... END` is optional for single statements.

Comment: i will @Ron, in 7 minutes ;-)

Comment: @MartinSmith true, but I always include them even for single statements for consistency and also to prevent confusion or worse when someone comes in and adds a second statement.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes I agree, I was just confused by the claim that "Begin and End is what i was missing" as it is not required here.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, I agreed with that part. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
alter procedure sp_updateThis
@something varchar(5),
@active char(1)
as begin
-- check to see if active and do the update
if(@active = 'Y')
Begin
update myTable set this=@something
End

-- run this one regardless
update yourTable set that=@something
```

Comment: @AdamPlocher - Yes according to the question text. No according to the code comment.

Comment: I know. I was confused with the question and the comments on the code. I just went by the comments.

Comment: it doesn't matter which to do as long as i know how to do it now :) thank you all again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're really trying to update every row in the table:

```
update myTable set this=@something where @active = 'Y';
```

Otherwise you probably want additional clauses there...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a procedure like this:
create procedure sp_updateThis
@something varchar(5),
@active char(1)
AS
 Begin

if @active ='y'
 begin
 update yourTable set that=@something
 end
 else
 update myTable set this=@something
  update yourTable set that=@something

end
  go